# Does ClearCase have a trigger for snapshot views?

Tags: triggers, view, clearcase

It seems like the Trigger extensibility feature in ClearCase has to be attached to a VOB by the owner. I would like something similar that I can administer myself for my local snapshot views. Does such a feature exist?

Comment: You basically can't do anything in ClearCase without a $100k/year administrator.

Comment: @Mike: darn... I should have a chat with my boss about a raise. I am a bit short of those $100k/year you mention ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "local trigger" per view in ClearCase.

When you create a **[trigger](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_u_trg_ovw.htm)** (with **[`mktrtype`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktrtype.htm)**), you can:

- attach it to a VOB
- check if you are in a snapshot view by reading the environment variable **`CLEARCASE_SNAPSHOT_PN`**

> (All operations executed in a snapshot view) The path to the root of the snapshot view directory in which the operation that caused the trigger to fire took place.

- check if you are in a snapshot view by reading the environment variable **`CLEARCASE_VIEW_KIND`**

> (All operations) The kind of view in which the operation that caused the trigger to fire took place; the value may be dynamic, snapshot, or snapshot web.

- checking if you are in the right view by reading the view tag **`CLEARCASE_VIEW_TAG`**

> (All non-UCM operations; for UCM, all deliver and rebase operations and setactivity) View tag of the view in which the operation that caused the trigger to fire took place.

- check if the trigger should execute itself for the right user: **`CLEARCASE_USER`**

> (All) The user who issued the command that caused the trigger to fire; derived from the UNIX or Linux real user ID or the Windows user ID.

---

With all those elements, you could write a script able to call a custom script versioned in the snapshot view, which means by convention (in a path defined in advance) you could define a script managed by the user for a snapshot view.

But unless you try that kind of indirection, there is no local trigger proposed *directly* by ClearCase.